# Angular HttpClient blocking Authorization header

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

Angular HttpClient doesn't seem to send headers.
I have checked the network calls (google chrome) and I see the headers are being displayed in the Request Payload section instead of being displayed on the Request Header section. 
Code and Network call screenshots are attached below.

Service:

```
submitproduct(url: string){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization','Token '+localStorage.getItem('token')),
      body: new HttpParams().set('url',url)
    };
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/custom/products/', httpOptions);
  }
```

**UPDATE**

chnaged the service code to

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                    .set('Authorization','Token '+token);
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/custom/products/', product , {
      headers,
    })
```

still facing the same issue, data is being sent while headers are not being sent.

Also I tried `fetch` method for one of the API and worked fine.

```
      fetch(baseUrl + '/auth/login-check/', {
          method: "GET",
          headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Token ' + token})
        }).then((response) => {
              return response.json();}) 
              .then((returnedData) => { 
                if (returnedData['success']){
                  this.logged_in = true;
                }
                else{
                  this.logged_in = false;
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error.message))
            });   
      }
```

Options Headers
[image: Options Headers]

Post Headers
[image: POST Headers]

Comment: The second parameter of a `post` is the message body, not the options. https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: @R.Richards I changed the code to 
`return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/custom/products/',null , httpOptions);` still request headers are not being sent. What changed is that I cannot see the Request Payload now.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient.post` expects the second parameter to be the body for the `POST` request. You can use the following to provide the headers correctly:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Token '+token
  })
};

return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/custom/products/', product , httpOptions );
```

You can use `{headers: headers}` too if sending header object as shown in your question. See below:

```
return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + '/custom/products/', product , {
      headers: headers,
    })
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, still getting headers are not being sent,
I tried to add other headers also, When added `Origin`, I got an error `Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"` which makes sense, But no-clue what's wrong with Authorization. 

Rechecked the backend also, but using postman it's working fine.

Comment: you mean headers for GET call?

Comment: I meant, other header params for the same request.

Comment: I feel, Authorization header is being blocked by angular HttpClient.